# Zebra .zpl file backwards to designer

Tags: designer, zebra-printers, zpl

I am still learning zpl.  I have created some simple labels using the Zebra designer and converted them to zpl files and added to printers.  Now, I have been tasked to update existing labels for some of our customers and I do not have the file available in the designer.  I have been successfully been able to do things like update a barcode type and add a field by directly updating the script.  But, the changes the users want would be much easier if I could use designer (I know that is like cheating!).  But, the timeline I have is short.  I have found some older questions out there that say this is not possible, so I thought I would check to see if it may now be possible to use the script on the zebra printer, and convert it to text that the designer will recognize.

I would like to mention that the printers I work with are physically located in other countries, with most inside restricted manufacturing production areas.  When testing, I have to coordinate with users who have access to these printers.  This means that printing one label, and then receiving a picture of this label can take several hours.  I am still waiting for results of one test we did yesterday!  Thanks to this site, I have found a site on line that will kind of mimic the label, but the actual printed copy is the best test.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot import the ZPL back into a designer, but there are two tools that are very helpful when you don't have a printer to test with:

[Labelary Online ZPL Viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html)

[Chrome ZPL Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo?hl=en-US)

I've used both and have been pleased with the results, but your experience may vary depending on the complexity of the label.

Comment: Thanks Elton, I appreciate your response.  I will check these tools out!

Comment: Great, if they work for you please consider marking as the answer.  Thanks!